# App service security - Strange routing problem

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the Azure Portal I received a security warning for one of my app services.
The warning tells that a potential running wordpress instance would potentially harm the computer of clients.

The route that the warning states is "wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/external/page/index.php"

And indeed - when I navigate this url in my app service, the browser shows this warning:

[image]

The strange thing is:

- Wordpress is not and never had been executed by this app service
- Angular is running with its own router. But the shown red message is definetely not part of my Angular app
- The web config does not contain any routes that could redirect to wp-content somehow.
- The wwwroot does not contain anything like this

This is the content of my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to www.example.com">
                  <match url=".*" />
                      <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(example\.com|example\.net|example\.asia|example\.cn|example\.com\.cn|example\.net\.cn|example\.de|example\.hk|example\.co\.in|example\.in|example\.com\.sg|example\.com\.tw|example\.tw)$" />
                      </conditions>

                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Allow LetsEncrypt" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".well-known/*" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>             
                <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(?!.*(.bundle.js|.bundle.map|.bundle.js.gz|.bundle.css|.bundle.css|.js|.css|.map|.gz|.png|.jpg|.ico|.svg|.woff|.txt|.gif)).*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"></conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>               
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can this be? Which casues the browser to navigate to this strange page... my web application works fine, but I do not underdstand where this page comes from.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have received a security warning for one of your app services in Azure Portal. The warning tells that a potential running WordPress instance would potentially harm the computer of clients. From my understanding, you mentioned that WordPress is not and never had been executed by this app service Angular is running with its own router.

Based on the information you provided, it is possible that your app service has been compromised and someone has injected malicious code into your app service. The injected code could be responsible for the redirection to the suspicious WordPress page.

I would recommend you check your app service logs and activity logs to see if there are any suspicious activities. You can also try to scan your app service for vulnerabilities using Microsoft Defender for Cloud.

1. Go to the Azure portal and navigate to your app service.
2. In the left-hand menu, click on "Log stream" under the "Monitoring"
   section. This will open a live stream of your app service logs in
   the browser.
3. You can also download the logs by clicking on "Download
   logs" in the top-right corner of the "Log stream" page. This will
   download a zip file containing the logs for your app service.
4. Alternatively, you can also configure your app service to send logs
   to a storage account or a Log Analytics workspace. To learn how to
   configure logging for your app service, see Enable diagnostics
   logging for web apps in Azure App Service.

Another item you can try is see if you can redeploy your site code to wipe out any code that might have been injected. Keep in mind though your local dev machine could also be the source for the malicious code as well. Depending on the intelligence of the malicious code, it may still remain after you redeploy.

If you are not able to find any suspicious activities or vulnerabilities, you can try to suppress the security alert for the resource1. To learn how to suppress security alerts, see Suppress alerts from Microsoft Defender for Cloud. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-app-service-introduction